# Searching for papers from a specific conference

Tags: literature-search, google-scholar

Is there a way to search, using Google Scholar or another tool, for all papers that appeared in a certain conference?

For example, I would like to find all papers that appeared in the recent "EC 17" conference. While I can see the papers [in the conference website](http://www.sigecom.org/ec17/toc.html), I do not have access to them so I would like to see them in Google Scholar too. I tried to use the "published in" field of their "advanced search", but [it did not give any meaningful results](https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?as_q=&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_occt=any&as_sauthors=&as_publication=EC%202017&as_ylo=2017&as_yhi=2017&btnG=&hl=iw&as_sdt=0%2C5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to search a single article to know how the citation manager in Google Scholar has extracted the information. You can then use the information to search the full proceeding.

For example, an article looks like this:

> Filippas, A., & Horton, J. J. (2017, June). The Tragedy of your Upstairs Neighbors: Is the Negative Externality of Airbnb Internalized?. In Proceedings of the 2017 ACM Conference on Economics and Computation (pp. 537-538). ACM.

[The required answer is here. You can see the full set of articles in this link under Google Scholar.](https://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?as_q=Proceedings%20of%20the%202017%20ACM%20Conference%20on%20Economics%20and%20Computation&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_occt=any&as_sauthors=&as_publication=Proceedings%20of%20the%202017%20ACM%20Conference%20on%20Economics%20and%20Computation&as_ylo=&as_yhi=&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5)

I hope you got the required answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the web site of the conference's organizer. The larger ones usually have at least the references (most also have the full text) on line.

A quick way to find them is to search for a particular paper you know was published there, and check the search results.